# Bigquery console does not show all tables

Tags: google-bigquery

We are now having 1144 tables in one dataset, but many of them are not listed in the left hand list of Bigquery console. I wonder if this is due to a set limit.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The BigQuery Web UI will only show 1000 tables in a dataset (likewise will show only 1000 projects and 1000 datasets in each project). I've filed a bug to either show a longer list or provide a way to load more in the UI.

In the meantime, however, you can use bq to list your tables:

```
$ bq ls --max_results=10000 your_dataset_name
```

Comment: thanks Jordan, look forward to future release on this.

Comment: On a relevant note, without parameters `bq` (and JSON API as well) lists only 50 tables.